# Change image recursively of table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am using `jquery.sortElement.js` to sort table. Sorting table with header is working. Now i want to add an image on header click for `ascending` and `descending` order. I added image successfully for ascending order.

Alignment of these images is not working.
I tried it with `display:table-header-group;` But all went too bad.

Problem-

1. Image is not aligned with table header, I want image to append after header text.
2. Second image for descending order is also not showing in header.

**Code I tried-**

```
var user_table = $( '#users' );
    $('#company_header, #user_header, #email_header, #type_header')
        .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
        .each(function(){

            var th = $(this),
                thIndex = th.index(),
                inverse = false;

            th.click(function(){
                  $('th').removeClass("image-append-up");
           $(this).addClass("image-append-up");

                user_table.find('td').filter(function(){

                    return $(this).index() === thIndex;

                }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                        inverse ? -1 : 1
                        : inverse ? 1 : -1;

                }, function(){

                    // parentNode is the element we want to move
                    return this.parentNode; 

                });

                inverse = !inverse;

            });

        });
```

**CSS styles-**

```
.image-down
{
   height:14px;
   width:14px;

    background:url("http://datahub.io/images/chevron-down.png") no-repeat;

}
.image-append-up
{
   height:14px;
   width:14px;

    background:url("http://datahub.io/images/chevron-up.png") no-repeat;
 background-position:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

I want images to replace recursively on `descending` and `ascending` order with proper alignment.

Here is Working fiddle- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/daqGC/5/)

Comment: That sorting function and then `inverse = !inverse`, mmmm, don't know, it just doesn't look right. There must be another way to do this more clearly.

Comment: @elclanrs, Please help me out if you know any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/daqGC/9/

You had an invalid value for the `background-position` property, it should be like this:

```
.image-append-up
{
   height:14px;
   width:14px;
   background:url("http://datahub.io/images/chevron-up.png") no-repeat;
   background-position:right 2px;
}
```